# D3 Trend Line Domain

Tags: d3.js

I draw a line chart using D3 with some data from our database, I got some data for the entire year to calculate what would be our trendline (taking some values for 8am, 12m, 4pm and 9pm), I'm drawing this in the chart with path and values for each X (time).

Now my problem is the domain of the trendline is of course bigger than our current values (lets say its 2 pm and my trendline will always go to 9 pm). The closes I got was setting the trendline's domain to my current data domain, which returns this:
[Test1](https://www.dropbox.com/s/2lpye4o2u590tip/test.PNG?dl=0)

```
xTrend.domain(d3.extent(trendData, function (d) { return d.date; }));
```

How can I cut it so it doesn't go beyond the SVGs width? I tried setting the width attribute and it doesn't work, so my guess is it has something to do with the domain.

If I set the trendline's domain to its data, I get this:
[Test2](https://www.dropbox.com/s/jk91wvuffimfl55/test2.PNG?dl=0)

```
xTrend.domain(d3.extent(data, function (d) { return d.date; }));
```

PS: While we are on this, if anyone can point me on how I could see if my line is above-below my trendline it would be great ;)

**Update:**
Thanks to @lhoworko
I added this

```
svg.append("defs").append("clipPath")
        .attr("id", "clip")
        .append("rect")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height);
```

And this to my line path

```
.attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)")
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at d3 clip paths. It will make sure the line beyond the end of the chart isn't displayed.

Take a look here.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/clipPath

Comment: Thanks this solved it! I added a clip-path rect with my width - height, and added it as an attribute to my trendLine path. Perfect! (Can't upvote, I'm still new here haha :( )